# What does middleware.use() do?

Tags: javascript, koa

I am confused how the use() function is used in JavaScript backend development.
I am using koajs as a backend framework, but I assume the questions holds valid for expressJS as well.

**app.use(middleware)**
=> Stacks middlewares on top of each other and thus defines a sequence of functions which are applied to the request before a response is created.

**middleware.use(...)**
=> I don't understand what this function does. Does it also create a stack? So it might create a stack which eventually will be inserted into the app stack?

Code exampleI :

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
 knex('users').where({ username }).first()
 .then((user) => {
   if (!user) return done(null, false);
   if (password === user.password) {
     return done(null, user);
   } else {
     return done(null, false);
   }
 })
.catch((err) => { return done(err); });
}));
```

Update:
I just stumbled across another code example.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should = chai.should();
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

Again middleware.use(...) is called.

Comment: You're asking what `passport.use` does? It's Passport's way of defining how it will work.

Comment: yes. So it is something passport specific?

Comment: This one is, but it's not an unusual pattern. I don't remember Passport but it may allow its own set of handlers to be registered with multiple use calls. It's just a function-what a given module does is up to the module, but in general, patterns like this have a fairly standard meaning.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the part "it may allow its own set of handlers to be registered with multiple use calls." Could you clarify?

Comment: If you call it twice it may add each passport handler to a list of handlers. I don't know, haven't used it for awhile.